# Поиск строки в файле с помощью регулярного выражения python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть шаблонная строка NNNNNNRR, где N - любая буква из набора A,T,G,C, a R - любая буква из A, T. как с помощью регулярного выражения сделать поиск всех строк такого формата в файле?
То есть алгоритм должен найти строки АААААААА, ААААААТТ, ААААААТА и так далее

кусок моего кода: он работает не так, как хотелось бы, причина скорее всего в нюансах работы .replace

```py
def PAM_finder(file_for_search, search_string):
    occurrences = []
    pattern = search_string.replace('R', '[AG]').replace('Y',
    '[CT]').replace('S', '[GC]').replace('W', '[AT]').replace('K', '[GT]').replace('M', '[AC]').replace('B',
    '[CGT]').replace('D', '[AGT]').replace('H', '[ACT]').replace('V', '[ACG]').replace('N', '[ATGC]')

    regex = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

    df = pd.read_excel(file_for_search)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
      row_str = ' '.join([str(cell) for cell in row.values])
      if re.search(regex, row_str):
        occurrences.append(row_str)

    resultfile = f'{file_for_search[:-5]}_PAM_{search_string}.txt' #name of result file
    with open(resultfile, mode = 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
      for string in occurrences:
        f.write(string + '\n')

    files.download(resultfile) #скачивание файла в гугл колаб


file_for_search = input('Введи название файла (ex. readme.xlsx): ', )
search_string = input('Введи PAM-seq (ex. NNNNNN): ', )

PAM_finder(file_for_search, search_string)
```

Comment: А зачем там replace?

Comment: replace задумывался как то, что он будет менять N на букву из [A, T, G, C]. но если я передаю в replace список букв, он N заменяет на список, а не на одну букву из списка(

Comment: Забавно. И как именно компьютер бы решал, на какую именно букву из списка нужно заменять?? replace заменяет первую заданную строку на вторую. А не "на одну букву из списка".

Comment: Ну и вообще ваш код не очень совпадает с описанием задачи.

Comment: да, код отличается, потому что мне было важно узнать только для примера, для остального я могла бы сама дописать то, что нужно)

Answer (score 2):

Вот регулярка:

```
[ATGC]{6}[AT]{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант решения. В функцию подается путь к файлу, шаблонная строка и словарь преобразования шаблона в регулярку. Регулярка формируется с помощью группировки подряд идущих одинаковых символов (модуль itertools, метод groupby). Далее считывается фрейм, данные (которые могут находиться в любых строках и столбцах) вытягиваются в один столбец (Series), удаляются пустые значения и фильтруются с помощью `.str.fullmatch(mask)`. Затем записываются в .csv без заголовков строк и столбцов.

Исходный файл `c:\test\test_PAM.xlsx`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код:

```
import itertools

def PAM_finder(file_for_search, search_string, mapping):
    mask = ''.join(
        f'{mapping[letter]}{{{sum(1 for x in go)}}}' for letter, go in itertools.groupby(search_string)).replace('{1}','')
    s = s = pd.read_excel(file_for_search).unstack().dropna().reset_index(drop=True).astype(str)
    s[s.str.fullmatch(mask)].to_csv(rf'{file_for_search[:-5]}_PAM_{search_string}.txt',index=False,header=False)

mapping = {'R': '[AG]', 'Y': '[CT]', 'S': '[GC]', 'W': '[AT]', 'K': '[GT]', 'M': '[AC]', 'B': '[CGT]', 'D': '[AGT]','H': '[ACT]', 'V': '[ACG]', 'N': '[ATGC]'}
PAM_finder(r'c:\test\test_PAM.xlsx', 'NNNNNNRR', mapping)
```

Результат - файл `c:\test\test_PAM_PAM_NNNNNNRR.txt`:

```
AAAAAAAA
AAAAAAGA
```